# Synology FileStation API

Tags: api, nas, synology

Hi I am trying to synology api to download a file, it seems that the API documentation is outdated,
I successfuly login and logut using the API,
but when I tried to use this api call

http://myds.com:5000/webapi/entry.cgi?api=SYNO.FileStation.Info&version=1&method=getinfo

the response sends error 103, "Method do not exists".
According with the documentation, first, you have to retrive the cgi path,in my case is "entry.cgi".
then you know that part of the  api direction 
/webapi/?api=&version=&method=[&][&_sid=]

According with the error 103 the   (in this case is getinfo) doesn't exists, but the documentation tells other thing.. and it's driving me crazy

https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Software/DeveloperGuide/Package/FileStation/All/enu/Synology_File_Station_API_Guide.pdf

Someone has used Synology api recently? I need to figure out how to use the SYNO.FileStation.Download api call.

Comment: Can you give examples of the exact commands you are trying to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you will need to look into the code of the filestation php files.
Here are some impressions of how this was done for the PhotoStation:

https://gist.github.com/anthonydahanne/4583444
https://blog.jbowen.dev/synology/photostation/getting-started/get-api-info/

Similar to PhotoStation I would first search for the info-method to check what the API is supposed to offer.

Answer (score 1):

I just happened to come across your thread, have you tried viewing the APIs available on your Diskstation? You can do that by calling

```
http://<YourDiskstationURL:Port>/webapi/query.cgi?api=SYNO.API.Info&version=1&method=query&quer%20y=all
```

I have a function that looks like the successor to the download function:

```
{"maxVersion":2,"minVersion":1,"path":"entry.cgi","requestFormat":"JSON"}
,"SYNO.FileStation.Download":
```

In the API-documentation `Synology` suggests to check whether a specific API is available or if it has changed.